# Does Windows 8 support wubi installation? 

Tags: installation, linux-distributions, wubi, windows-8

I recently installed Windows 8 from MSDN. I used to install Linux within Windows in my Windows operating systems.

But when I tried to install my Ubuntu 10.10 with Wubi installer the option to install with wubi was disabled.

Help me to install Ubuntu with Wubi installer on Windows 8 if Windows 8 supports it. If it does not, please recommend any other alternative to Wubi. I use Wubi mainly because I can easily remove the Linux operating system.

Comment: You could try installing in a virtual machine. You have the full linux functionality and it is very easy to uninstall.

Comment: @vignesh4303 I did read recently that Ubuntu were thinking of getting rid of Wubi, in their next release 13.04

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would say the correct question is does WUBI support Windows 8. I built a program a while back called BEeN GRUBed. Completely Open Source and I consider it to be WUBI on crack. It even works when installing Linux from Windows 9x systems.

Comment: could u link the tool with the link

Comment: I didn't want to spam also I built it before Windows 8 so please tell me how it works. http://sourceforge.net/projects/grubed/

Comment: sure i ll give it a try